# How do I replace function commerce_customer_options_list with my own?

Tags: commerce

How can I replace

```
/**
 * Implements hook_options_list().
 */
function commerce_customer_options_list($field) {
```

in commerce_customer.module around line 949 with my own options_list build routine?

the hook is just sent directly to the commerce_customer module, and I don't see how I can hijack it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using [hook_field_widget_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) in your custom module for either `$context['field']['type'] == 'options_list'` or of type `options_select` ... it looks like the widget is set as `options_select` in `commerce_customer_field_widget_info_alter`. I'm pretty sure its 1 of the 2 values.

Then you can set a `#pre_render` attribute to a function that alters the default commerce_customer supplied values. A derived example from the API comments is:

```
$element['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_pre_render_commerce_customer_options_field';
```

Then in your pre_render function you can add/remove values from the list. I think i've done this once before myself for god knows what ... haha.

Alternatively, you could also probably set or unset values from any old FAPI `#options` array in a `$form` with `hook_form_alter`. Hopefully 1 of these 2 approaches gets you there.

Also, you'll probably want to be sure your module invokes after commerce_customer.